# Wordpress mapping with add_rewrite_rule and regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, mapping, regex-negation

I am stuck at my mapping in wordpress.

I have three `add_rewrite_rule()` functions:

(1)

```
add_rewrite_rule('products[\/](.+)[\/]?$', 'index.php?range=$matches[1]', 'top');

add_filter(
    'query_vars',
    static function ($query_vars) {
        $query_vars[] = 'range';
        return $query_vars;
    }
);

add_filter(
    'template_include',
    static function ($template) {
        $range = get_query_var('range');
        if ($range) { 
            return  __DIR__ . '/range.php';
        }
        return $template;
    }
);
```

(2)

```
add_rewrite_rule('product[\/](.+)[\/]product][-]page[\/][\?]code=(.+)$', 'index.php?rangeofproduct=$matches[1]&code=$matches[2]', top');

add_filter(
    'query_vars',
    static function ($query_vars) {
        $query_vars[] = 'rangeofproduct';
        return $query_vars;
    }
);

add_filter(
    'query_vars',
    static function ($query_vars) {
        $query_vars[] = 'code';
        return $query_vars;
    }
);

add_filter(
    'template_include',
    static function ($template) {
        $varCode = get_query_var('code');
        if ($varCode) { 
            return  __DIR__ . '/product-page.php';
        }
        return $template;
    }
);
```

(3)

```
add_rewrite_rule('/products[/](.+)[/](.+)[/]$', 'index.php?productsrange=$matches[1]&family=$matches[2]', 'top');

add_filter(
    'query_vars',
    static function ($query_vars) {
        $query_vars[] = 'productsrange';
        return $query_vars;
    }
);

add_filter(
    'query_vars',
    static function ($query_vars) {
        $query_vars[] = 'family';
        return $query_vars;
    }
);

add_filter(
    'template_include',
    static function ($template) {
        $varHttpName = get_query_var('family');
        if ($varHttpName) { 
            return  __DIR__ . '/family.php/';
        }
        return $template;
    }
);
```

With the first one I would like catch the `range` placeholder (that differ according to different ranges of lights) in links like http://example.com/products/led/, http://example.com/products/halogen/ or http://example.com/products/fluorescent/.

With the second rule I would like to catch placeholders `rangeofproduct` and `code` as in http://example.com/products/led/?code=123456789.
Here problems start. The `rangeofproduct` placehoder never gets any value. The `range` placholder still does (I don't know why!). So I could use this one. It maps alright because I use the mapping with `$varCode`.

The third rule is probably the most challenging. It seems that the first rule takes precedence and immediately takes the links like the following: http://example.com/products/led/a60-standard-led/. I went online to https://regexr.com/ and indeed the (.+) from the first rule is good enough also for `'led/a60-standard-led'`.

Can anybody help me with this?

The questions are:

(1) Do I need differ the names in placeholders for the same thing (`range`, `rangeofproduct`, `productsrange`).

(2) Why the `rangeofproduct` doesn't enter the `$query_vars`?

(3) Is it OK if I use `matches[1]` in all three rules or should I have in the first rule `matches[1]`, in the second rule `matches[2]` and `matches[3]` and finally in the third rule `matches[4]` and `matches[5]`?

(4) How should I write regex that would exclude `'led/a60-standard-led'` in the first rule. I tried to find a solution in [Regex: match everything but specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern) (a string containing specific text (say, not match a string having foo) section). But my knowledge of regex is less than basic so I couldn't adapt the solution to my case `'led/a60-standard-led'` excluding `'/'` in the middle.

The answer that I wish at most is the answer to the fourth question.

Comment: Try changing your `(.+)` to `([^/]+)` which is “match everything that isn’t a forward slash”. Use that in any area that comes before a forward slash

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisHaas! It's better now! The rule: add_rewrite_rule('product[/]([^/]+)[/product\-][page/?code=](.+)$', 'index.php?rangeofproduct=$matches[1]&code=$matches[2]', 'top'); now gets both placeholders. In http://example.com/products/led/?code=123456789 rangeofproduct=led and code=123456789. But the 2nd rule rules out the 3rd one although it's completely different. I tried with (\d+) instead of (^/]+) to collect just digits at the end but I lost rangeofproduct. Does the regex checker in PHP differs from e.g. https://regexr.com/? Thank you so much Chris - I'll need to pay somehow all that.