# Define the URL of the sales store without Dokan

Tags: php, wordpress

i would like to make a page like a simple Dokan store but without dokan.

For this, I have a template in section with the content I want to display, but I can't find a solution to display the section with the content.

In dokan, you need to define the URL of the selling store.
As in this image:
[image]

Here's the button that gives me the page with a URL /ecopepeites/carre-cotons:
[image]

For these images, it's a version of the site that no longer meets your needs.

How can I define the URL of the selling store without dokan?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If it is just a page... can't you use a page? Otherwise, if you want to register a URL that you programmatically do whatever, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67305267/231316

Comment: Thanks for sharing the post.
For the page, it is a section that behaves like a page, as the information must change depending on the seller chosen by the customer.

I have a listing of sellers by category and a button that gives more information on the selected seller.

Comment: Than that link I posted should be what you are looking for. You register a path, along with a dynamic portion, and tell WP to pass the dynamic portion in a custom query string parameter. Then you register the QS parameter with WordPress. And finally, when WordPress attempts to load files, you check for the existence of you custom QS parameter and then do whatever you want. 100% official WordPress way.